# HTML5 video tag in IE plays 2 tracks simultaneously instead of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have this page

http://joewillhelpyou.com 
Users click the blue botton and a video page begins to play.

I have it simple. an iframe so the Jquery dows not mess with my  tag that I found would not allow me to autoplay the next video, and 2 src for each video. In all the browswers they work okay, only one video is played back mp4 or webm. but in IE I keep hearing two playing back and I cannot figure out why

you can visit the page and tell me if you catch my mistake or a workaround for IE

```
<div id="videodiv">
<iframe src="http://joewillhelpyou.com/videos/step2/play02_01.html" width="1000" height="750"></iframe>
</div>
```

then this leads to a page where I have the video

```
<video controls autoplay width="936" height="624">
<source src="002_001.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="002_001.webm" type="video/webm">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

under normal situations the code only plays one choce right? but in IE it seems to play 2 things at once, the rest of the browsers only sound out one track and that is what I want

Comment: Post relevant code in question. What will happen once you have fixed your issue in your website? Your question wouldn't be of any more help for any futur readers with similar issue

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.`

Comment: Edited with code now :)